# Javascript set base object when declare methods in prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I read that declaring object methods in prototype is good approach because it saves memory and allows to change implementation in any time for all objects.
But what i need to do when i need to set base object for object that uses prototype method declaration?
Example:

```
function Animal() {
   this.age = 0;
   this.weight = 0;
   //other properties
}

Animal.prototype = {
   //some methods for Animal
}


function Dog() {
   //properties for Dog
}

Dog.prototype = {
   //some methods for Dog
}
```

So, how can i set Animal as a base class(object) for Dog(because prototype property in Dog is implemented as custom object for methods)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ES5 version** (still most common, but I wouldn't recommend it - see ES6 version)

Based on this post [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/10/22/classical-inheritance-in-javascript-es5) you need to use Object.create like this:

```
function Animal() {}
Animal.prototype = {};

function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype = Object.create( Animal.prototype );
```

Also see this solution with [Object.assign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171256/881032) (sadly IE doesn't support it)

**ES6 version**

```
class Animal {
  // all your methods come in here. No more prototype needed.
}

class Dog extends Animal {

}
```

You can already use ES6 even though most browsers don't completely support it yet. Use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile you JS.

Comment: Oh, it's so easy, thanks.
But when i set Dog.prototype to Animal.prototype i can access methods but can't access properties from Animal.

Comment: Or i shouldn't access them? I should call getters and setters, right?

Comment: Well - I would use the extend variant. It is still common practice. But of course: it depends on what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

You could define `Animal` as a function and use its constructor to set an instance of it in the `Dog` prototype :

```
Dog.prototype = new Animal();
```

More complete code :

```
var Animal = function () {    
   this.age = 0;
   this.weight = 0;

    this.age = function () {
        return this.age;
    }
    // define other methods ...    
    // ...
    return this;
};

var Dog = function () {           
    // overriding the age 
    this.age= 10;    
    // define or override methods ...    
    // ...
    return this;
};

// Dog extends animal
Dog.prototype = new Animal();    

// Creating an instance of Dog.
var dog = new Dog();
```